# Where can I find data sets on jet fuel prices, including futures and options?

Tags: airline-operations, fuel

I understand that most airline companies buy jet fuel using hedging instruments such as futures and options. I have been searching on the internet data sets of having both jet fuel and option prices. Can someone give me a link or a research paper which has these data values?

Comment: This may be of relevance: https://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/research/fimrc/papers/jet_fuel.pdf

Answer (score 1):

[Airnav.com lists current fuel prices at most airports (that they can get data for)](http://www.airnav.com/airport/KPHL). Keep in mind that airlines may (and most likely do) get a bulk discount based on the volumes they buy in.You may want to take a [look at this](https://www.mercatusenergy.com/blog/bid/81973/a-beginners-guide-to-fuel-hedging-call-options), and keep in mind they may also trade on [kerosene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerosene) futures as that is what jet fuel is made from.